# Get items for the last few hours

Tags: python, django, django-models

In the model there is a field `DateTimeField()`, the database stores the value of the form 2015-09-21 17:37:11. How to make a selection, for the last several hours. For example, in the sample were only the values for the last 3 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

delta = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=3)
Model.objects.filter(date_time__gte=delta)
```

Comment: What's the `[-3:]` here? Also you couldn't do negative indexing on queryset, django would give you exception `AssertionError: Negative indexing is not supported.`

Comment: I misunderstood he means 3 hours.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the date reference manually, and use it in the query.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
before = now - timedelta(hours=3)

qs = MyModel.objects.filter(date__gte=before)
```

As a reference, the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module.
Note that if you use locale-aware times in your application (through [USE_TZ=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_TZ) setting), you will need to change the way you get current time to this:

```
from django.utils import timezone
now = timezone.now()
```